# StackOverflowError unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I know that a `StackOverflowError` is thrown when recursion goes too deep (about 25000 recursions), but, after testing, I found that the *exact* amount of recursions before it is thrown (max stack size) changes between programs. Also, if I run an infinitely recursive method, say, 10 times, the SOE is thrown after *a* recursions the first time, and *b* recursions the next nine times (i.e. a different amount of recursions the first time). Also, both *a* and *b* differ between running my test multiple times.

Here is my class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> sizes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int size = doTest();
            System.out.println("Test " + i + " Yielded result " + size);
            sizes.add(size);
        }
        System.out.println("Average: " + average(sizes));
    }

    private static double average(Collection<Integer> ints) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : ints) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum / (double) ints.size();
    }

    private static int executions = 0;

    private static int doTest() {
        try {
            recurse();
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            int exec = executions;
            executions = 0;
            return exec;
        }
        throw new Error("Unexpected behaviour: StackOverflowError not thrown!"); // just to keep the compiler happy
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("InfiniteRecursion")
    private static void recurse() {
        executions++;
        recurse();
    }
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
Test 1 Yielded result 23004
Test 2 Yielded result 25060
Test 3 Yielded result 25060
Test 4 Yielded result 25060
Test 5 Yielded result 25060
Test 6 Yielded result 25060
Test 7 Yielded result 25060
Test 8 Yielded result 25060
Test 9 Yielded result 25060
Test 10 Yielded result 25060
Average: 24854.4
```

But, if I run my program again, it looks like this:

```
Test 1 Yielded result 23279
Test 2 Yielded result 25074
Test 3 Yielded result 25074
Test 4 Yielded result 25074
Test 5 Yielded result 25074
Test 6 Yielded result 25074
Test 7 Yielded result 25074
Test 8 Yielded result 25074
Test 9 Yielded result 25074
Test 10 Yielded result 25074
Average: 24894.5
```

Can someone tell me why these differences are occurring between programs, and on the first test?

Java version: 8 update 5

Comment: There is no line saying "this many recursions and you're done". It depends on what exactly happens in the method and what is already allocated on the stack.

Comment: Programs get a *sane* amount of stack space. Each function which is currently entered uses some amount of it (though I'm not sure exactly how java handles it). The amount of stack space you get can change depending on any number of factors, e.g. How much ram the system has available when your program starts, which OS you're running, whether it's a Tuesday...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The depth of recursion depends on your stack size and how fast you use it up.  The exact stack size isn't always the same (exactly why I don't know) but you should avoid getting anywhere near this limit as another machine will be very different by default.

Comment: Well that explains the difference between running this program multiple times, but why is it different on the first test to the rest?

Comment: @bcsb1001 Try adding `-XX:+PrintCompilation` I suspect your code is being compiled so after the first usage it uses a little less memory.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be it. Thanks!